# VueJS cshtml component

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core

I want to use VueJS with .NET Core Razor pages.

**boot.ts**

```js
import './css/site.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: require('./components/home/home.vue.html') },
    { path: '/counter', component: require('./components/counter/counter.vue.html') },
    { path: '/fetchdata', component: require('./components/fetchdata/fetchdata.vue.cshtml') }
];

new Vue({
    el: '#app-root',
    router: new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes }),
    render: h => h(require('./components/app/app.vue.html'))
});
```

Notice the **fetchdata.vue.cshtml** in the code above. When I run the application, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./ClientApp/components/fetchdata/fetchdata.vue.cshtml
Module parse failed: .\NetCoreVueJs\ClientApp\components\fetchdata\fetchdata.vue.cshtml Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|     <div>
|         <h1>Weather forecast</h1>
 @ ./ClientApp/boot.ts 9:37-91
 @ multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client? 
path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.ts
```

Is it possible to use **.cshtml** files as components in VueJS?

Comment: Why do you want to use `.cshtml` files? `.cshtml` is a Razor view which runs *on the server* (only if you invoke it through a controller though). Vue on the other hand runs solely on the client and shouldn’t even have access to `.cshtml` views. Maybe you can show us why you want to use `.cshtml` here in the first place.

Comment: I want to use tags, for example `asp-for` on my input fields. I want to use the same model defined in .NET Core in two places: backend (.NET Core) and frontend (Vue.js).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Vue in your razor pages, but I think you're approaching it in the wrong way. Remember that the .cshtml files are compiled in the backend side into html markup that is sent to the browser.

If you want to use razor views you will have to mount your VueJS code on the HTML that is generated and sent to the browser. See [his example I created on Codepen to illustrate this, I'm using Pug to mimic something that generates the HTML template and once it is generated I mount Vue JS on it. https://codepen.io/jaireina/pen/MNvvgd

**Pug**

```
#app
    input(type="text", placeholder="type your name", v-model="name")
    each val in [1,2,3]
    p.name {{name}}
```

**JS**

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: ''
  }
})
```

You won't be able to use Vue in the way you're trying, as a single page application and passing it the cshtml files as templates. If you really need to use razor views you can do something to what I mentioned before. But if you want to create a SPA, I would recommend creating an API with .NET and having your Vue app consuming that API.

I hope this helps.